# is it better/faster to make a select table.field than make a table.* when using big databases?

Tags: mysql

By simple logic Id think yeah, is faster because the DBMS brings less info and needs less memory...however, I dont have a valid argument why could be faster.

If for example, I want to have a select from 2 related tables, with index and everything.

But I want to know why `select tableA.field, tableA.field2, tableA.field3, tableBfield1, tableB,field2 from tableA, tableB`

is actually faster than

```
select * from tableA,tableB
```

Both tables have about 3 million records and table A has about 14 fields and tableB got 18.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is faster or not, but generally speaking it is better "form" to specify all field names. It documents which fields code consuming the results may depend on, and forces field ordering within a row. Many an application has been brought down because someone reordered the columns on the server.

Comment: do you mean that explicitly selecting all fields is faster than select *?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference if you're selecting the same fields. It's just syntax, it doesn't affect how the query is processed.

Comment: yeah, explicity select which fields vs select all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the number of fields selected means that less data has to be transmitted from the server to the client. It also reduces the amount of memory that the server and client have to use to hold the data selected. So these should improve performance once the server determines which rows should be in the result set.

It's not likely to have any significant impact on the speed of processing the query itself within the database server. That's dominated by the cost of joining the tables, filtering the rows based on the `WHERE` clause, and performing any calculations specified in the `SELECT` clause. These are all independent of the columns being selected. If you use `EXPLAIN` on the two queries, you won't see any difference.

Comment: are not the same fields, the * gets about 32 fields, if I specify them I only bring about 8

Comment: When you wrote "the fields used for the search will be the same" I thought you were talking about the fields you were selecting. I misunderstood.

Comment: no, are less, way more, thats why  I want to know if will be faster than make a select all (I believe yes)

Comment: I know, I said I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

you are joining two tables with 3 million rows each with no filter. that will make 9x10^12 rows. generating and transmitting to the client a resultset of a few fields, against all 32 fields will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you select all fields in the first query it's the same thing because you request the same amount of data. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27987/2

Maybe the difference of perfomance has another reason...like...other selects in running.

Essentially select * from tableA,tableB is the equivalent of the *[Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)* of the two tables, for a total of 3million x 3 million of rows.

Therefore:

```
select * from tableA,tableB
```

With the wildcards * you retrieve a table of 9million x 28 columns, while

```
select tableA.field, tableA.field2, tableA.field3, tableB.field1, tableB.field2 from tableA, tableB
```

with the explicit form you have a table of 9million x 5 columns...so less data!

Comment: I understand with specific selection of fields I will consume less memory of the server, right? but the query will return faster? (in theory.. yes..)

Comment: @jpganz18 my guess would be at best it would only be a few milliseconds faster (as MySQL wouldn't have to verify your result fields exist and/or can be calculated), but that only counts assuming you are actually going to use all the fields returned; with Alessandro's example of 9 million rows, you need to remember that one INT field you don't care about is near 36 MB of data that must be handled by the server AND transferred over the connection.

Comment: Theorycally is the same...if you look at the two sections _execution plan_ on the link above (sqlfiddle) you can notice that are the same...this mean that the db executes the two queries in the same way